# MdProgressBar buffer background color in Angular Material

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, progress-bar

I'm using [progress bar](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/overview) from Angular Material and trying to custom-style it. I can set the borders, radiues, color of the progressed part (buffer?) simply by styling the element itself (e.g. `md-progress-bar { border: 1px solid black }`) but I cannot add the background color for the bar.
If I change the background color of the `.mat-progress-bar-buffer` via dev tools, it works, but if not via component css (or any other css, for that matter).

So, this doesn't work:

```
.mat-progress-bar-buffer {
  background-color: $white;
}
```

What else can I try?

Edit: [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/WFhDlQdt0kb25MF6YX6S?p=preview)'s a simple plunker to play with.

Comment: tried !important?

Comment: Yep, of course :)

Comment: I am not sure they used `background-image` with some svg in `.mat-progress-bar-background`.

Comment: Try opening the plunker, find that element in dev tools. If you add background-color: white to it, it works.

Comment: plunker not working, clean state btw.

Comment: Fixed the plunker link btw.

Comment: May be your override is not working because of the theming (indigopink.css) you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will be any better, however since /deep/ and >>> will be deprecated from browsers support, angular have it's own way to emulate this using `::ng-deep` and is the prefer way until better solution is found.

[Documentation on angular](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles) says it will be deprecated however on [github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17867#issuecomment-312322174) vicb mention that they have no plan to remove `::ng-deep` in a near future.

Usage is similar to `/deep/`:

`::ng-deep .mat-progress-bar-buffer {}`

Comment: I know /deep/ is going away, but I need this for now. Anyway, TIL about `:host ::ng-deep` :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's due to ViewEncapsulation. If I add `/deep/ .mat-progress-bar-buffer`, the style is applied.

I'd still like to find a better solution (with /deep/ being all but gone).